# How to change Bulk Wordpress Post Status?

Tags: php, wordpress, post

Is it possible to Published all Draft Posts using SQL or Function code? I tried using this code in my function file, but not works.

```
add_action('admin_init','wpse_244394');

function wpse_244394(){
    $args = array('post_type'=> 'post',
         'post_status' => 'draft',
         'posts_per_page'=>-1
    );
    $draft_posts = get_posts($args);

    foreach($draft_posts as $post_to_publish){
       $query = array(
        'ID' => $post_to_publish->ID,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
       );
       wp_update_post( $query, true );  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use "wp_publish_post( $post_id )" instead of "wp_update_post".

```
    add_action('admin_init','wpse_244394');

    function wpse_244394(){
    $args = array('post_type'=> 'post',
        'post_status' => 'draft',
        'posts_per_page'=>-1
    );
    $draft_posts = get_posts($args);

    foreach($draft_posts as $post_to_publish){
        wp_publish_post( $post_to_publish->ID );
    }
}
```